# Set value of property to value of another views property in XML?

Tags: android, android-layout

In Android's XML layout system, I'd like to be able to set the value of one views property to the value of another views property.

For example, something like this:

```xml
android:layout_marginRight="@id/rightBarButton:width"
```

Would set the `marginRight` value of this view to the `width` value of the `rightBarButton` view.

I already know I can do this programmatically, but is there a way to do this in XML?

Comment: "but is there a way to do this in XML?" -- in some cases, you may be able accomplish this sort of thing via data binding. In this case, I suspect that what you want will be impractical (you can't observe the width of a widget). Also, data binding is somewhat of a dead-end technology, as Jetpack Compose will be making layout resources obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

Use constraint layout you don't need to specify margin just give right constraint of button1 to left constraint of buttonRight like this

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="button1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

this result image [image: this result image]

another example [image]

its code

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="button1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Barrier example

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="button1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:barrierDirection="left"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="btn1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

result image:

[image]

Comment: Could you please give a more complete sample? Thanks.

Comment: @ChristianB edited the answer with example

Comment: The reason this solution doesn't facilitate what I'm asking is that i don't want the two views to need to be side-by-side. I may want a view to be in a completely unrelated location to the other view, but still, have its right margin bound to the width of the second view.

Comment: @NathanF. do you know about barriers in ConstraintLayout maybe this is solution for your case please read the answer i have added two more exapmles

Comment: It still doesn't facilitate exactly what I'm wanting. I want a value of a property to be bound to the value of another property. Let's say for example i have `view1` that is constrained to the right side of the parent, and then i have `view2` also constrained to left side of some arbitrary container view. But i want the `rightMargin` of `view1` to be bound to the width of `view2`. From a layout perspective, the two views are not associated. Only the values of the properties are associated.